# Height 100% causes scroll bar to appear

Tags: html, css

This question is everywhere and the solution is always the same but it never works for me and I have no idea why! I simply need my div to fill the entire view port without creating a scroll bar. Who knew this would be so difficult. Everyone says to just set body and html margins to zero but this doesn't work. I still have a vertical scroll bar! I'm getting really frustrated and I would really appreciate some help. Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/davdarobis/d3k4hv6q/23/.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

#content
{
    height: 100%;
    border: solid blue 5px;
    margin: 0;
    
}

#heading {
  height: 40%;
  border: solid red 5px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>  

<div id="content">

    <div id="heading">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>

</div>


</body>
```

I can't use the `top: 0` `bottom: 0` solution because this seems to screw up the `height: 100%` property of its children. I'm completely stuck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably the border.

Comment: Try height 100vh. This tells that the height will be 100 view height of the screen.

Comment: why would you want the body on absolute anyway?

Comment: @ShioT I think the same

Comment: It's the border.. to solve read this [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `border: solid blue 5px;` is causing the scroll bar to appear.

It ends up having 10px more height than the parent element "body" (5px bottom +5px 
 top).

if you really need a border, you subtract it from the 100%.

Comment: Oh wow I always thought borders were drawn around the inside of the container not the outside. This helps a lot! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Apply the property `box-sizing: border-box;` to all of your elements (selector `*`) so the extra space caused by borders, padding, and margins is then included in the 100% and not added to the 100% (i.e. 100% + 5px border).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

#content
{
    height: 100%;
    border: solid blue 5px;
    margin: 0;
    
}

#heading {
  height: 40%;
  border: solid red 5px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>  

<div id="content">

    <div id="heading">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Portrait_Placeholder.png" alt="" class="image">
    </div>

</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to html tag an overflow property like so:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `100vh` in place of `100%` for `height` and also set `box-sizing:border-box;` for all elements, I have made some changes to the css, please check if it works

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
body, html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#content
{
    height: 100vh;
    border: solid blue 5px;
    margin: 0;

}

#heading {
  height: 40%;
  border: solid red 5px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on top of your css, that should prevent scrolling

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```